# Unable to access .env file from the Front-End

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, google-oauth, vite

I am building a react app with vite which utilizes @react-oauth/google that requires me to write my clientId. I did it through `clientId={process.env.MY_CLIENT_ID}` which would break my application with the error 'process is not defined'.

I've dug a bit through vite documentation on .env and found that they have their own way of doing `process.env` through `import.meta.env`, or at least I just understood these two are equivalent; here is the documentation [link](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) if wants to take another look. After I changed my clientId to `import.meta.env.MY_CLIENT_ID` browser was able to render my application again, but now I received another error.

```
m=credential_button_library:45 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given client ID is not found.
```

`credential_button_library` is `<GoogleOAuthProvider></GoogleOAuthProvider>` from `@react-oauth/google dependency` which requires `clientId=''` as an attribute.

Noting that code works fine when I simply just paste the value of my client id into clientId, I console logged the value of `import.meta.env.MY_CLIENT_ID` and got 'undefined', instead of the value stored in my .env `MY_CLIENT_ID = somerandomcode` (in case the error lies in .env file here's how inside of it looks). I went to Vite documentation again and saw that the possible cause was that my variable did not start with VITE_, so I changed its name to `VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID= somerandomcode` but that did not fix it.

*Update*
With @adsy's suggestion I tried to change my vite config using this [blog](https://dev.to/whchi/how-to-use-processenv-in-vite-ho9). This is what my new configs look like:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
    const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
    return {
        define: {
            'process.env.VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID': JSON.stringify(env.VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID),
        },
    };
});
```

Although this allowed me to use process.env without the error I described at the top of my post, the output of console.log(process.env.VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID) is still undefined.

*Update*

I resolved the issue. The problem was that I did not put .env file in the right place ;).

Comment: When you tried `VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID` in the `.env` file I assumed you also changed the usage in code to `import.meta.env.VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID` to match and restart dev server? Just checking. You are on the right track so far -- you do need `import.meta.env` and yes you need to prefix with `VITE_`. What is `credential_button_library`? It seems like there is some other code possibly looking for `process.env.MY_CLIENT_ID`. Is this your code?

Comment: If that code is third party, and you really just want it to be defined on `process.env` without the prefix, you can do it by using `define` in your vite config. See https://dev.to/whchi/how-to-use-processenv-in-vite-ho9. This basically avoids the requirements around `VITE_` and `import.meta` and may be needed if you have third party code not using these guidelines.

Comment: @adsy yes correct i added the prefix inside the .env file as well, I forgot to include that.

Comment: @adsy `credential_button_library` is <GoogleOAuthProvider></GoogleOAuthProvider> from @react-oauth/google dependency which requires clientId='' as an attribute. I will edit that in my post as well so it is clearer.

Comment: @adsy I tried implementing those changes in my vite configuration file. It resolved the previous error of  `process being undefined`, but it did not resolve the latest problem, when I console log the value of `process.env.VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID` the output is still undefined.

Comment: Can you edit your OP with your new vite config?

Comment: @adsy I am sorry, what is OP?

Comment: "Original post"

Comment: @adsy Oh, yes of course.

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed this part in [the documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files) that you linked:

> To prevent accidentally leaking env variables to the client, only variables prefixed with VITE_ are exposed to your Vite-processed code. e.g. for the following env variables:
>
> ```
> DB_PASSWORD=foobar
> VITE_SOME_KEY=123
> ```
>
> Only VITE_SOME_KEY will be exposed as import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY to your client source code, but DB_PASSWORD will not.
>
> ```js
> console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY) // 123
> console.log(import.meta.env.DB_PASSWORD) // undefined
> ```

In your case, you'll probably need to prepend `MY_CLIENT_ID` in your .env file with `VITE_`, so it'll look like this:

```
VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID=...
```

Then your variable should be accessible in your client-side code via `import.meta.env.VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID`.

In this, Vite is following the same pattern that many frontend build frameworks follow. For example, [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) requires you to prepend client-code-accessible env vars with `VUE_APP_`.

Comment: I think its still `import.meta.env.VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID`? Like it doesn't remove the prefix automatically...I may be wrong.

Comment: I've tried that, and it still does not work. When I console log `import.meta.env.VITE_MY_CLIENT_ID` the output is undefined.